# Synch SMS Verification with 6 digits instead of 4

Tags: ios, swift, sinch, sinch-verification

The Synch SMS verification I get is only 4 digits. How do I make it 6 digits?

Below is the code I am using. This code just seems to send 4 digits for verification whereas I would like it to be 6 digits.

```
var verification: Verification!  // this is defined in the class

private func initiateVerification() {
    verification = SMSVerification(applicationKey: SinchConstants.applicationKey, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    verification.initiate { (success, error) in 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if success {
                self.handleSuccess()
            } else {
                if let error = error where error.code == -1001 {
                    self.handleSuccess()
                } else {
                    self.handleError(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this done anywhere? I've looked at their docs and there is nothing there indicating that you can choose between 4 or 6 digit code. https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/ios/#smsverification

Comment: I see it on their internet site, please look at the picture.  That is why I am thinking they have this feature. https://www.sinch.com/products/verification/sms-verification/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant control it in the dashboard, but I am happy to change it for you if you mail in your appkey and that you want to 6 digits to support@sinch.com

Comment: Thank you @cjensen. I just did.